# iOS UITableViewCell - this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numberMessages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom cell and a custom class for the cell. All works fine until I wire in IB the property of a label in the custom class. I get this error:

2014-11-11 17:35:18.018 Project[41210:7583517] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numberMessages.'

I'm not getting why it crashes. The file's owner class is set to "TimelineHead". I have the property and it's wired. Here is the "TimelineHead" class, first the header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TimelineHead : UITableViewCell {
}
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *numberMessages;
@end
```

and the actual class:

```
#import "TimelineHead.h"
@implementation TimelineHead
@synthesize numberMessages;
...
...
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The simulator will occasionally cache storyboard/nib information. Try cleaning your project and running it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the custom UITableViewCell subclass to the wrong object in the xib file. You need to assign that class to the root view object in your xib which is the cell (the first entry you see in the list of views on the left, below First Responder). File's owner has to be set to the default NSObject. Than you link your outlets from your cell to the subviews.